# Displaying Pushpins with Bing Map for WP7

Tags: windows-phone-7, xml-parsing, bing-maps

I'm trying to display a list of positions (from a xml document:using xml reading) in a Bing map with WP7,using the method below, but it doesn't work. 
When i tried to see what my function is reading, i found out that it's not extracting the Longitude.Where's the problem?

```
void frloc_DownloadStringCompleted(object sender, DownloadStringCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Error == null)
        {
            ListBoxItem areaItem = null;
            StringReader wkstream = new StringReader(e.Result);
            XmlReader wkreader = XmlReader.Create(wkstream);

            string areaName = String.Empty;
            string Nom = String.Empty;
            string Photo = String.Empty;
            string Latitude = String.Empty;
            string Longitude = String.Empty;
            string Timing = String.Empty;

            while (wkreader.Read())
            {
                if (wkreader.NodeType == XmlNodeType.Element)
                {
                    switch (wkreader.Name)
                    {
                        case ("name"):
                            {
                                Nom = wkreader.ReadElementContentAsString();
                                areaItem = new ListBoxItem();
                                areaItem.Content = Nom;

                            } break;
                        case ("photo"):
                            {
                                Photo = wkreader.ReadElementContentAsString();
                                areaItem = new ListBoxItem();
                                areaItem.Content = Photo;
                            } break;
                        case ("latitude"):
                            {
                                Latitude = wkreader.ReadElementContentAsString();
                                areaItem = new ListBoxItem();
                                areaItem.Content = Latitude;
                            } break;
                        case ("longitude"):
                            {
                                Longitude = wkreader.ReadElementContentAsString();
                                areaItem = new ListBoxItem();
                                areaItem.Content = Longitude;
                            } break;

                    }
                    double lat, lon;
                    double.TryParse(Latitude, NumberStyles.Any, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, out lat);
                    double.TryParse(Longitude, NumberStyles.Any, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, out lon);
                    GeoCoordinate Loc = new GeoCoordinate(lat, lon);

                    Pushpin wkpin = new Pushpin();
                    Image wkpinImage = new Image();
                    wkpin.Content = Nom;
                    wkpinImage.Source = new System.Windows.Media.Imaging.BitmapImage(new Uri("http://weenek.com/markers/" + Photo, UriKind.Absolute));
                    wkpinImage.Opacity = 0.8;
                    wkpinImage.Stretch = System.Windows.Media.Stretch.None;

                    imageLayer.AddChild(wkpinImage, Loc);
                    map1.Children.Add(wkpin);
```

The xml:

```
<resultat>
  <ami>
    <id>547</id>
    <nom>Hakim</nom>
    <prenom>Abidi</prenom>
    <latitude>37.01406741589469</latitude>
    <longitude>11.02375026562504</longitude>
    <date>2011-12-02</date>
    <time>01:09:35</time>
    <image>175.jpg</image>
  </ami>
</resultat>
```

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing wrong with your code except of that you're never setting the coordinates of the Pushpin.

Try adding

```
wkpin.Location = Loc;
```